# Ruby Arrays - Are there any elements where the sum of the elements to the left equal the sum of the elements to the right?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Given a Ruby Array, I need to find if there exists an element where the sum of the elements to the left of the element is equal to the sum of the elements to the right of it.

Example

```
[1,2,3,3]
```

The element is 3, because the sum of the elements to the left of 3 [1,2] equal the sum of the elements to the right of 3.

I'm not sure how to solve this, but I will give it a shot.

```
def left_equal_right(array)
  array.any? do |x|
    index = array.index(x)
    array[0..index-1].inject(:+) == array[index+1..-1].inject(:+)
  end
end

array.any?([1,2,3,3])
=> returns true, but I'm not sure this method works for larger arrays.
```

Comment: If you aren't sure whether it works for larger arrays, then...try it with larger arrays? I'm confused about why you're asking a question about a working solution. Also, is this a typo? `array.any?([1,2,2,3])`, because you aren't actually calling your routine

Comment: Don't use `array.index` when there might be duplicate elements.  It will only ever find the first one.

Comment: yes, that was a mistake. I meant to say [1,2,3,3]. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @Mark Reed, excellent advice. Index won't work with duplicate values. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to @Max's solution, though I can terminate the search early when all elements in the array are non-negative. That's because the difference between the right sum and left sum would be monotonically decreasing as one steps through the array.

My answer assumes that there must be at least one element on each side, but it could of course be modified to permit zero elements on one side.

**Code**

```
def balance(arr)
  return nil if arr.size < 3
  all_non_neg = (arr.min >= 0)
  enum = arr.to_enum
  last = enum.next
  diff = arr.reduce(:+)-last
  (1..arr.size-2).each do |i|
    val = enum.next
    diff += -last - val
    return i if diff.zero?
    return -i if all_non_neg && diff < 0
    last = val
  end
  nil
end
```

Here, when the search terminates early, I return the negative of the index where that occurs. That's just for illustrative purposes; `nil` would be more appropriate.

**Examples**

```
balance [1,1,1,1,1]                 #=> 2
balance [-1,-1,-1]                  #=> 1
balance [3,4,-6,7,5,-6,4,3,5,2]     #=> 4
balance [3,4,-6,7,5,-6,4,3,5,2,4,7] #=> nil
balance [3,7,2,28,6,5,8,7]          #=> 1
balance [3,7,2,28,6,5,8,7]          #=> -4
```

As indicated, in the last example the search was terminated at index 4.

Answer (score 5):

This should be fastest since it doesn't sum the whole array every iteration:

```
def left_equal_right ary
  left = 0
  right = ary.reduce(:+)

  ary.each do |x|
    right -= x
    return true if left == right
    left += x
  end

  false
end
```

On my VM this checks a 10 million element array in 2 seconds.

Comment: This looks like an O(n) solution which is nice. I think mine was only an O(n^2). Excellent work.

Comment: One might think that if the index at which the balance occurred was also wanted, `return true if left == right` could simply be changed to `return i if left == right`, but that doesn't work, as that would produce: `left_equal_right [0,1,-1] #=> 0`

Comment: @Ajedi32, that's a good point. I suppose it depends on what the OP means by "the sum of the elements to the left of the element is equal to the sum of the elements to the right of it". In my answer I assumed that there had to be at least one element on each side, but, but either interpretation may be appropriate, depending on the application.

Comment: I chose this interpretation of the question just because the code for it is short and cute. :P

Answer (score 3):

Works for arrays of length 10,000 (just a few seconds)

Times out for arrays of length 100,000

```
left_equal_right (1..100_000).to_a
# =Execution timed out.
```

However, if you modify your code in the following way:

```
def left_equal_right(array)
  array.any? do |x|
    index = array.index(x)

    left_sum = 0
    right_sum = 0
    left_index = 0
    right_index = 0
    while left_index < index
      left_sum += array[left_index]
      left_index += 1
    end

    while right_index < array.count
      right_sum += array[right_index]
      right_index += 1
    end
    return left_sum == right_sum
  end
end
```

Then you can handle much bigger arrays, I tried up to 10 million:

```
left_equal_right (1..10_000_000).to_a
# ==> false
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this - better way to get the indexes:

```
array.each_index.any? do |i|
  array[0..i-1].inject(:+) == array[i+1..-1].inject(:+)
end
```

This still does a lot of unnecessarily-repeated work, but it gets the job done and avoids the problem your solution introduces by using `Array#index`.

Comment: This solves the problem of the initial solution finding only the index of first element when there are duplicates

Comment: Excellent solution. But I've never seen _ as a parameter in a do block for each_with_index. I usually see |e,i|. What does the |_,i| do?

Comment: `each_index` would be slightly cleaner here. @DarkMouse - `_` indicates that this variable will not be used - some IDE's complains about local variables not being used.

Comment: @BroiSatse - Indeed. if you didn't have 2 variables in the block, you would get a wrong number of arguments error. But that is very useful. Thank you

Comment: @DarkMouse - not exactely. Blocks behaves more like proc than lambdas, it will never raise an error if it receives different number of arguments than expected.

Comment: @MarkReed - Also `array[0..i-1]` can be written as `array.first(i)` and `array[i+1..-1]` as `array.last(array.size - i - 1)` - some might find it more descriptive.

Comment: @BroiSatse Thanks, but I was just copy-and-pasting from OP's code and changing only what I needed to change to correct the problems, not going for maximally idiomatic Ruby.  Anyway, I would use `array.drop(i+1)`.